# NSIS to set default program to launch specified file type

Tags: java, jar, nsis

I am using an NSIS script to create an installer for my Java program. My executeable jar is launched from a BAT file. The installer works fine, but I want a specific file type (just for an example ".zip") to always use my app as the default. Right now if I double click the file, I have to browse into "Program Files > Company Name > bat file" and specify to always use this BAT file to launch this file type.

Is there a way to specify this in an NSIS script so the user doesnt have to browse and set that always use checkbox? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the helper [macros](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File_Association) from the nsis wiki, or just handle it on your own with the registry functions using [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144175%28VS.85%29.aspx) as your guide